# Using Babel to convert ES6 modules to ES5 AMD modules, not working as expected

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, amd, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I hope someone can help.

I'm using grunt-babel to convert my ES6 module code to ES5 AMD module code. Here's my ES6 code:

multiply.js

```
export default function (x,y) {
    return x * y;
};
```

square.js

```
import multiply from 'multiply';
export default function (x) {
   return multiply(x,x);
};
```

app.js

```
import square from 'square';

var myValue = square(2);
console.log(myValue);
```

As you can see, all I'm doing is creating a module 'multiply', importing that into another module 'square', and then finally using 'square' in my main js file. The above 3 files then gets converted to the following:

multiply.js

```
define("multiply", ["exports", "module"], function (exports, module) {
    module.exports = function (x, y) {
        return x * y;
    };
});
```

square.js

```
define("square", ["exports", "module", "multiply"], function (exports, module, _resourcesJsEs6moduleExampleMultiply) {
    var _interopRequire = function (obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj["default"] : obj; };

    var multiply = _interopRequire(_resourcesJsEs6moduleExampleMultiply);

    module.exports = function (x) {
        return multiply(x, x);
    };
});
```

app.js

```
define("app", ["exports", "square"], function (exports, _resourcesJsEs6moduleExampleSquare) {
    var _interopRequire = function (obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj["default"] : obj; };

    var square = _interopRequire(_resourcesJsEs6moduleExampleSquare);

    var myValue = square(2);
    console.log(myValue);
});
```

The problem I have is that I expected the 'app.js' file to be converted to something more like this:

```
requirejs(['square'],
    function (square) {
        var myValue = square(2);
        console.log(myValue);
    }
);
```

In my gruntfile.js my config is pretty simple:

```
options: {
    moduleIds: true,
    modules: 'amd',
    blacklist: ['strict']
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually I don't understand what is your problem? I think your compiled by `babel` code is working after all. It is convenient for `babel` to compile the code this way.

Comment: Hi Alez, thanks for the response. Maybe its my lack of experience with all this, but I understood that a define() only gets generate if there is an 'export'? And if there is only an 'import', a requirejs() gets generated.

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging I finally realised where I went wrong.

In my current stack I'm forced to use Almond, instead of RequireJS. Because of this, Almond expects there to be a file to initialise the modules, hence why I was expecting Babel to generate one for me. But as it turns out, the code generated by Babel will work fine within RequireJS, but for it to work with Almond, I need to create a seperate es5 js file, just to initialise the files generated by Babel.

Something like this:

```
requirejs(['app'],
    function (app) {
        app();
    }
);
```