# Using Webpack and Babel to convert ES6 to AMD

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm using webpack in my app, and have babel converting my js/jsx files from es6 to es5.

I'd like to have babel convert the module loading in these files to AMD. I see how to do this with grunt-babel:
[Using Babel to convert ES6 modules to ES5 AMD modules, not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963263/using-babel-to-convert-es6-modules-to-es5-amd-modules-not-working-as-expected)

How would I do this if I want webpack to handle the babel conversion?

For example, in webpack.config.js I have:

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel'
  }
}
```

Can I set an option in there for Babel to use AMD?

Comment: What would be the point of this? Since webpack is still bundling it all, they'd behave the same.

Comment: @loganfsmyth -- do you mean to say that in its default configuration, Babel will convert es6 'import's to an es5 asynchronous module loader? From what I see, I think it's converting to commonjs, which is why I'd like to explicitly set it to AMD. But if I'm mistaken, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: My Point is, even if you tell Babel to create AMD modules, you it doesn't matter because the final result is a Webpack bundle, which is neither CommonJS nor AMD, and having the individual files be AMD makes no difference.

Comment: Ah I think I understand. My biggest concern is whether the modules will load asynchronously... it sounds like that will happen regardless if I set the module loader to "amd" or not, correct?

Comment: The webpack bundle is the thing that loads, so by the time it is ready to run, the output format from Babel will behave identically whether it is AMD or CommonJS. What would "load asynchronously" mean in the context of Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an options for babel with `query` key:

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        modules: 'amd'
    }
  }
}
```

For all available options take a look here: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate the whole bundle as AMD module, you can set it in the "output.libraryTarget" config:

```
{
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "amd"
  }
}
```

See here, in "output.libraryTarget":
https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. (And the accepted answer didn't.) My use case: Already having webpack/es6 setup for other purposes and wanting to output a module that could be used in another app based on requirejs.